# Adding value to a list in a functional component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add new values to a list every time I press a button but am having trouble doing this. Here you will find the codesandbox I have made, that has all the code to make it easier to understand what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-taussig-ufyby

The Messages.jsx has an array of existing values called messages that is being output as a list.
I would like to be able to press the IconButton found in the CustomizedButton,jsx and be able to add more items to the list found in the Messages.jsx.

If any further explanation or clarification is required, just let me know.

Comment: Hello you need to add more value while click on button ?

Comment: yes, more values to the list when button click so I can have Name 4, Name 5 etc @MehulJariwala

Comment: you need to maintain the state globally in app js or some main file let me update the code

Comment: Hello @john i did

Comment: I don't see any changes made to the project @MehulJariwala

Comment: Please see entire updated project here once you satisfied then i will raise the answer you can give correct mark https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-feather-do4zw?file=/src/listz.jsx @john

Comment: Yes this is perfect, can you explain to me what you did so I understand @MehulJariwala

Comment: please see the footer text and get me on that i will explain you perfectly

Comment: okay, can you put this as an answer so I can choose it as the answer for this post @MehulJariwala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `messages` state to a central component, like `listz`, update `CustomizedButton` to take an `onClick` callback, and pipe all the correct props through to each component.

CustomizedButton.jsx

```
export default function CustomizedButton({ onClick }) { // pass onClick prop
  return (
    <IconButton onClick={onClick} color="primary"> // attach to button onClick handler
      <DirectionsIcon />
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

Message.jsx

```
function Message({ messages }) { // pass messages prop
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map(({ id, primary, secondary }) => (
        <React.Fragment key={id}>
          <ListItem className={classes.ListItem} button alignItems="flex-start">
            <ListItemText
              className={classes.ListItemText}
              primary={
                <Typography type="body2" style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
                  {primary}
                </Typography>
              }
              secondary={<Typography type="body2">{secondary}</Typography>}
            />
          </ListItem>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

listz.jsx

```
const messagesData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    primary: "Name 1",
    secondary: "Second 1111"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    primary: "Name 2",
    secondary: `Second 222222222`
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    primary: "Name 3",
    secondary: `Second 222222222`
  }
];

export default function Listz() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(messagesData); // set initial state

  // create add message handler
  const addMessage = () =>
    setMessages(messages => [
      // spread existing state
      ...messages,
      // add new message object
      { id: uuidv4(), primary: "test", secondary: "secondary 3334444555" }
    ]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Toolbar />

      <GridList cellHeight={50} className={classes.gridList} cols={1}>
        <List className={classes.list}>
          <Message messages={messages} /> // pass messages state as prop
        </List>
      </GridList>

      <CustomizedButton onClick={addMessage} /> // pass addMessage as prop
    </div>
  );
}
```

## *Edit*

#### Using an input to set the message secondary property

CustomizedButton.jsx

Add a button type attribute to the CustomButton

```
export default function CustomizedButton({ onClick, type }) {
  return (
    <IconButton onClick={onClick} type={type} color="primary">
      <DirectionsIcon />
    </IconButton>
  );
}
```

listz.jsx

Add a react ref to be attached to the input.

```
const inputRef = useRef();
```

Update `addMessage` to take an event object

```
const addMessage = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { value } = e.target.secondary; // get the input's value
  setMessages(messages => [
    ...messages,
    { id: uuidv4(), primary: "test", secondary: value }
  ]);
  inputRef.current.value = ""; // clear the input
};
```

Place the text input and `CustomizedButton` with `type="submit"` in a `form` element, and move the `addMessage` callback to the forms `onSubmit` handler.

```
<form onSubmit={addMessage}>
  <label>
    Enter Secondary message
    <input ref={inputRef} name="secondary" type="text" />
  </label>
  <CustomizedButton type="submit" />
</form>
```

Just is *just* one way to use an input, there are numerous ways to go about this.

[image: Edit amazing-napier-gumpn]

Comment: you are hardcoded the value secondary 3334444555 he need that also dynamic i guess

Comment: @MehulJariwala OP can generate new messages, id included, however they see fit. Question was about how to add more messages to the array via button click. These are messages so presumably a user or some other input is generating that content. "secondary 3334444555" seemed about as random as the initial "test" data.

Comment: This is a very good answer, thank you so much, I will look play around with the code to see if I have any questions about it, but thank you again @DrewReese

Comment: This works for this scenario, but the problem is if I was to replace the button with another component like a input form, I would not be able to get the value from the input and add it to the list using this way @DrewReese

Comment: @John You can modify `addMessage` to take an event object, other parameters, or both, to fit your needs. If you had a form with inputs what property or properties would/should it set in a message object?

Comment: only the secondary message prop @DrewReese

Comment: @John Updated answer with *an* example using an input.